# Change a value when a value get updated

Tags: php, mysql

I know there's this statement `ON UPDATE`, is there a way to use it to create a column in my database and when this value change, another predefined value is set to 0 ? 
Thanks in advance.

Exemple:

```
id | value | type
1      2      5
2      4      6
3      7      8
```

if i update the value of the first row, i want the type to set automaticaly to 0.

Comment: I'm not sure with the question. Please provide example input and expected result along with relevant example data

Comment: You can use trigger feature of SQL after update saying for each new row set Type to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a trigger that gets executed for every time row changed, for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_update_type BEFORE UPDATE
ON your_table_name
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    if NEW.value <> OLD.value THEN
        SET NEW.type = 0;
    END IF;
END;
```

After this, for everytime you do query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET value = '10' WHERE id = 1;
```

If the value is different that the old one, trigger will gets executed and type will be set to `0`

Here's how to set trigger from phpMyAdmin:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution, You can do this just with the help of php code.

first of all whenever your update function/action is triggered then also update the type value as well.

Comment: possible in sql as well, i.e while updating the first value also update the type along with, to 0

Answer (score 0):

Remove all access to `insert`, `update` and `delete` SQL statements from your PHP script. Just use stored procedures instead. That way the database can look after itself and maintain its own consistency.

Answer (score 0):

need use [mysql trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) for this row